# Disable CapsLock not working permanently in Monterey on M1

Tags: macos, monterey, caps-lock

I noticed that the obsolete and annoying CapsLock key reverts to default after even an hour.
I set it to No Action, but it reverts to CapsLock later.

Is this a bug in macOS ?
[image]

Comment: Is you Mac managed? (for example issued by an employer?)

Comment: No it is my own Mac.
I have an Intel MBP 2018 with the same version 12.3.1 and that does not show that problem.

Comment: Do you have any apps, utilities or tools installed that handle keyboard related stuff? (like custom macro appp, keyboard remapping tool, etc.)  - Have you installed or made any configuration "synchronization" stuff yourself? - or anything where you manipulated plists yourself or similar?

Comment: No I don't have any keyboard handler installed.

Comment: Does this happen if you create another user account and login there?

Comment: Now it works fine without explanation, Capslock is permanently disabled.